# Unused argument using Replace in R

Tags: r, replace

im trying to replace the maximum value of each row with -Inf.

```
    set.seed(1)
    mat <- matrix(sample(1:15), nrow = 5)
    #mat
    #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
    #[1,]    4    9    2
    #[2,]    6   10   13
    #[3,]    8   14   12
    #[4,]   11    5   15
    #[5,]    3    1    7


    max.col(replace(mat, cbind(1:5, max.col(mat)), -Inf))
    #Error in replace(mat, cbind(1:5, max.col(mat)), -Inf) : 
  unused arguments (cbind(1:5, max.col(mat)), -Inf)
```

im getting that error.

What might be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try again. It works perfectly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. The output is `[1] 1 2 3 1 1`.

Comment: turns out the problem was i defined another function called replace. dumb error i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Can do like this to replace the maximum value of each row with -Inf:

```
apply(X = mat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) replace(x, which.max(x), -Inf))
```

Comment: This is a loop. Try your best to avoid loops. Use vectorized functions

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

- the code shown does not produce an error message, rather it returns a vector having one element per row such that the ith element is the column number of the second largest element in that row.
- if you remove the outer `max.col` it does replace the maximum value in each row with `-Inf`.

Thus try this:

```
replace(mat, cbind(1:5, max.col(mat)), -Inf)
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4 -Inf    2
[2,]    6   10 -Inf
[3,]    8 -Inf   12
[4,]   11    5 -Inf
[5,]    3    1 -Inf
```